# Memory Issues with Gitlab 10 CE on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-16.04, sidekiq, unicorn, gitlab-ce

Tried posting on Gitlab's forum and had no luck so I thought I'd try here.

We’ve been using Gitlab10 CE for a few months now. We are a pretty small shop with only 5 developers so our instance of gitlab is busy but not crazy by any stretch of the imagination, yet we are constantly running into memory problems. It is a virtual machine running on Ubuntu 16.04. I initially began with the recommended 1 core, and 4GB of memory, and we were constantly being alerted about memory and CPU issues. I upped the specs to 2 cores, and 8GB of memory. Same issue. I’ve now pushed the box to 8 cores and 32GB of CPU and I am still constantly being alerted about memory issues (although the CPU has died down quite a bit). As of the time of this message, we’ve received 20 memory alerts in the last 5 hours. These things are even coming in through the night hours when we have no one even touching the system.

When I run HTOP, there are 28 processes called sidekiq 5.0.4 gitlab-rails [0 of 25 busy] that claim to be costing 2% of our overall memory each. That is over 16GB worth! Under that there’s a whole host of unicorn workers costing 1.8% of our overall memory each.

We’re pretty new to using gitlab so there could easily be something I’m just missing. Any advice on how to throttle the number of processes for each of these or throttle git’s overall memory consumption would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet you are seeing threads, not processes in htop.  Press Shift-H to view processes.  Those threads are all sharing the same 2% of memory.

Make sure you are keeping up to date with GitLab versions, they fix bugs and optimize their code all the time.